# Shall we change the name oDesk to Upwork in all the existing questions and answers as the name was changed officially?

Tags: discussion, editing

I saw the name of [oDesk](http://executiveinsweatpants.com/odesk-is-now-called-upwork/) was changed to [Upwork](http://www.upwork.com) in the website itself and in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODesk) too and the website is redirecting to `www.upwork.com` but still I saw so many posts having the name oDesk.
Shall we edit those names to Upwork? Is it wrong If I edit those names?

Note:
There are 122 search results for oDesk : https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search?q=odesk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, introduce the `Upwork` tag and mark `oDesk` as a synonym. Then modify `oDesk`'s tag summary to advise that people use `Upwork` instead

Answer (score 2):

I personally feel this would be a minor change, bumping questions unnecessarily. If people don't know it's changed, they should comment, asking the OP to edit it or correct it. If we mass-change, we're going to have a lot of questions bumped up, possibly losing any new questions that still need answers, from the front page.

Comment: +1 Valid Points.